# Passing a number to be sequentially deducted from start from a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have an numpy array like so

```
np.arrange(1,5)
```

which results in

```
array([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

Now I generate a random number between and it is **3.5**

I want to start deduction of 3.5 sequentially from right such that the result array is

```
array([0, 0, 2.5, 4])
```

**Basically deduct until and pass to next. Only the last number be -ve**

Also note that if the number was **15** in that case the resulting array would be

```
array([0, 0, 0, -5)]
```

Comment: This looks trivial, have you tried anything? What went wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a shorter version of the `reduce` function in Tahseen's answer.  I avoided the name reduce to avoid any confusion with reduce as in 'map & reduce'.

```
import numpy as np 

def cut( arr, amt ):
    """ arr is a 1d numpy array of floats or ints.
        amt is an int or float scalar to 'cut' it  by. 
    """       
    result = arr.cumsum() - amt 
    # result is of type float if either arr or amt are float.
    # amt is automatically broadcast to the shape of arr.

    # Set all apart from the last item to zero if negative.
    # max( 0, -ve value ) is 0
    result[:-1] = np.maximum( 0, result[:-1] ) 

    # Take the first differences along result, retain result[0]
    result[1:] = np.diff( result )
    return result
```

**Edit:**
Using Tahseen's suggestion of clip and replacing `np.diff` with `np.minimum` saves 10 micro seconds on a 1000 element array.

```
def cut( arr, amt ):
    """ arr is a 1d numpy array of floats or ints.
        amt is an int or float scalar to 'cut' it  by. 
    """       
    result = arr.cumsum() - amt 
    # result is of type float if either arr or amt are float.
    # amt is automatically broadcast to the shape of arr.

    # Set all apart from the last item to zero if negative.
    result[:-1] = result[:-1].clip(0)

    # Return the minimum of result or the input arr
    return  np.minimum( result, arr )
```

Comment: @Tis Chris am impressed by your solution. When you said shorter version in Tahseen's answer means you worked on my solution to further optimize it ?

Comment: Instead of np.maximum( 0, result[:-1] ) you could just use result[:-1] = result[:-1].clip(0)

Comment: @Tahseen I'm very used to a `cumulate, process, decumulate` pattern which was my first instinct.  I realised that the start of your answer was just explicitly doing what mine did but it diverged with your use of arithmetic with boolean results.  Your use of minimum replaces the need to take the `np.diff` and is slightly faster.

Comment: I think you pushed the optimization to max possible. Outstanding!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Using simple array iteration this can be done. Don't know whether there are any inbuilt numpy methods to do such thing in efficient manner.

```
import numpy as np

value = 11
arr = np.array([1,2,3,4])

def reduce(array, val):
    for i in range(len(array)):
        if(array[i]>=val):
            array[i] = array[i]-val
            return array
        else:
            val = val - array[i]
            array[i] = 0

        if(val==0):
            return array

    else:
        array[-1] = array[-1] - val
        return array


print(reduce(arr, value))
```

Comment: Interestingly your code is best optimized from performance perspective with Numba JIT decorator compared to other answers although it is very verbose

Comment: I think  numpy  "cumsum" function and "nonzero" functions should have at least o(n) time complexity for a  1d array theoretically.  So when we use both those functions the array we use to calculate will get traversed twice in a worst case. May be that is the reason. Not sure though.

Answer (score 1):

You can use basic numpy operations:

```
import numpy as np

def deduct_until(a, number=0):
    # convert to float numpy ndarray if necessary
    a = np.asarray(a, dtype=float)

    # calc cumsum
    ac = a.cumsum()

    # check if number is greater than cumsum, if yes, return zeros
    if number >= ac[-1]:
        a = np.zeros_like(a)
        # set the last number to the "accumulator" value
        a[-1] = ac[-1] - number
        return a

    # subtract limit and clip to 0
    ac = (ac - number).clip(0)

    # find first non-zero entry
    ind = ac.nonzero()[0][0]

    # set all values below ind to zero
    a[:ind] = 0
    # set value at ind to result of cumsum at ind
    a[ind] = ac[ind]

    return a
deduct_until(range(1, 8), 3.5)
# array([0. , 0. , 2.5, 4. , 5. , 6. , 7. ])
```

Comment: this fails if the number is greater than the sum of numbers in array. But good work I must say. I had been using logic gates to work out something and will share. I have tested it for many use cases but I don't know where it can fail

Comment: @Tahseen I fixed it by checking the result of the cumsum and returning only zeros if the number exceeds the sum of all values.

Comment: I also fixed my solution and wrote the answer in detail

Comment: there is still problem in your code. Last number is the accumulator so it is allowed to be negative as I wrote above. Whereas you return all 0 in that case. arange(5) and deduct 15 from your function and test with mine

Comment: It is not stated in the question that the numbers can be negative. Please add the relevant information to the question, not your answer. Please also add the expected output for your test cases. This solves the question as stated.

Comment: It was mentioned. Now I have highlighted it bold and also gave one more example where the number is larger than the cumulative sum

Comment: I didn't know what "be -ve" was supposed to mean, and I assumed it was a typo. What *is* it supposed to mean? I Changed the case of the number being larger than the cumsum.

Answer (score 1):

I thought I should write in detail for others and for myself also to not forget in future. I have described my approach in code comment in detail

```
def reduce(numpyarray, sequentially_deduct=0):

    # Substract deduction value from each element of b, the cumulative sum array passed to function
    d = numpyarray.cumsum() - sequentially_deduct

    # Create Boolean array out of this to know which are the numbers greater than 0
    dg0 = d > 0

    # Multiple this logical array of True/False with d and also with array passed with function
    # And then pick the minimum of the two elements at each position
    # This clears out cumulative sum and brings back array with values positive results in d and
    # also the elements of original for True positions 

    final = np.minimum(dg0 * d, dg0 * numpyarray)

    # If the deduction number passed was too large then all values of final would be zero
    # so in that case check the left most element, if that is also zero means we need to 
    # Logically NOT the the position and multiple it by last element of d, which is negative
    # And add it to the last element of final, which is hold zero and has to be over written
    # If last of d is zero, then any which way that would be written 

    final[-1] += np.logical_not(final[-1]) * d[-1]

    # Final return value
    return final
```

Comment: I like the use of the arithmetic with boolean results although my experience of this is that it's more difficult to follow the logic a few months later.  The minimum inspired the use of minimum in the edit to my answer above.